# Is there a good resource for days to maturity for different varieties of garden vegetables?

Tags: vegetables, harvesting, resources

I'm aware that many seed packets have "days to maturity" listed on the back. I've heard that this is a vague term because some sellers list days to maturity assuming some indoor growth before a plant is transplanted. Also, the term is used interchangeably with "days to harvest" and the true definition of "days to maturity" should refer to the plant producing viable seed.

It would be nice if there was a resource (internet or book) that clearly defined its use of the term "days to maturity" and that listed the values for vegetables of different varieties.

For example:
Early Girl Tomato - 50 days (from transplant)
Beefsteak tomato - 85 days (from transplant)
(and ideally listed how long the plant start should have been growing before being transplanted)

This would make it easier to plan a garden with a staggered harvest, and also just easier to get  the overall picture of when I can expect to harvest certain vegetables that I planted.

Do you know of good resources other than seed packets? (I might no longer have the packet/ have planted seeds from other sources.)

Answer (score 1):

I love the [Johnny's Selected Seeds](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/) company and their [free catalog](https://www.johnnyseeds.com/shop-johnnys/online-catalogs.html) for this reason among many others. The pictures are pretty, it's got entertaining and educational tidbits mixed among the products, and they have tons of great plants.

On the seed descriptions the first thing after the name of the seeds is the days to maturity. They also have ideal seed germination temperature charts you can read. Below is a screenshot where you can see the time to maturity for some beans. Capitano are 52 days and Jumbo are 55 days.

[image: johnny's seeds beans catalog]

There are possibly other sources, but Johnny's is one that is worth recommending.

Disclaimer: I do not work for them nor have any financial association. I'm not "spamming" for them I just love the great information they put in their catalog.

Comment: Your kindly tip & link are appreciated; its nice, & adds value when advertisers use a bit of their space to include helpful & interesting information

Answer (score 0):

There is so much variation in "days to maturity" due to specific growing environments and weather conditions, that any such tabulation would be useless. Non-beginner gardeners will ignore the claims to be found in gardening books and seed catalogs and rely instead on their own past experience, or perhaps some ultra-local informational resource if such is available.